# Find coordinates of polynomial in the basis of $1,x,x^2,\dotsc, x^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Jut have never seen this type of problems before.

So I have the polynomial:

$$f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \ldots + a_nx^n$$

and have to find its coordinates in the basis:

$$1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n$$

How should I act?

Comment: Ask your self, what does a coordinate in the basis mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its coordinates with respect to the given basis are
\begin{equation}
(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n)
\end{equation}
because it's expressed as a linear combination of the elements in the basis with coefficients $a_0,\dots,a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for choosing this basis is because the we can read the coordinates directly from the power-ordered polynomial. The polynomial $f$ becomes the vector $f$ in the monomial basis:
$$
f =
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 a_{0} \\
 a_{1} \\
  \vdots \\
 a_{n}
\end{array} \right]
$$

For example, the polynomial $y = 1 - x^{2}$ has the vector representation
$$
 \left[ \begin{array}{r}
 1 \\
 0 \\
 -1
\end{array} \right]
$$